# Stuck on Wordpress CSS change the plugin button Colour

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

Hi I am new on here first of all nice to meet you all

I am facing a problem on wordpress

I am using "Quick Download Button" Plugin which the link is https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-download-button/#description

after I have install it on my site I tried to change the button colour by css but I never ever success to change it. I have checked the button in inspect and I copied it but it didn't work.

what I tried was

```
.g-btn.f-l 
    {
    color: #3c1c1c;
    }
```

but it never worked.

please anyone help will be awsome thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you provide a browser deverloper-tools screen shot with styles applied to this element? For now it looks like a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue. Try quick-and dirty `.g-btn.f-l.f-l.f-l.f-l.f-l.f-l.f-l` selector (adding same class to increase selctors specificity). This is a bad style, but is okay for debugging purposes.

Comment: Like @jared said - it shouldn't be too hard to find the right selector and change the color within your browsers dev-tools. If you see the color change, bingo! Then if that doesn't work within your css file itself, you might have an ordering issue with your sites css files (i.e. your css is loading before the plugins). Quick way to test this is add the !important selector to that rule on your file - e.g. color: #3c1c1c !important;

Comment: thank you to both of you solve the problem! it was what user1138 told me. the problem was ordering issue thanks again to both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @jared said - it shouldn't be too hard to find the right selector and change the color within your browsers dev-tools. If you see the color change, bingo! Then if that doesn't work within your css file itself, you might have an ordering issue with your sites css files (i.e. your css is loading before the plugins). Quick way to test this is add the !important selector to that rule on your file - e.g:

```
color: #3c1c1c !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

the css color-parameter is not defining the color of the button, but from the text of the button. if you want to change the color of the button, you need to look after "background" or "background-color".

example:

```
.g-btn.f-l{
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  Background-color: #3c1c1c;
}
```

Visible example:

[image]

Source of example: [Kryptonews Lexikon](https://news-krypto.de/das-grosse-krypto-lexikon/)